# Scraping HTML using php

Tags: php, html, apache, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following text from the given text

Scrape:

1. Promise Me This (Between Breaths, #4)
2. The image with the src as http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1402555544l/22077246.jpg
3. A new love will test the boundaries of passion between a privileged boy next door and the tattooed, blue-haired girl who helps him embrace his wild side...\n\n\nNate has developed quite a playboy reputation around campus. It\'s not that he doesn\'t respect or trust women; he doesn\'t trust himself. The men in Nate’s family are prone to abusive behavior—a dirty secret that Nate’s been running from his entire life—so Nate doesn\'t do relationships. But he can’t help himself around one girl…\n\nJessie is strong, independent, and works at a tattoo parlor. Nate can’t resist getting close to her, even if it’s strictly a friendship. But it doesn\'t take long for Nate to admit that what he wants with Jessie is more than just friendly.\n\nWith Jessie, he can be himself and explore what he’s always felt was a terrifying darkness inside him. Even when Nate begins to crave her in a way that both shocks and horrifies him, Jessie still wants to know every part of him. Testing their boundaries together will take a trust that could render them inseparable… or tear them apart

HTML:

```
<div class="leftAlignedImage bookBox">

<div class="coverWrapper" id="bookCover646987_22077246">
<a href="/book/show/22077246-promise-me-this"><img alt="Promise Me This (Between Breaths, #4)" class="bookImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXMoh.jpg" title="" width="115" /></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
      var newTip = new Tip($('bookCover646987_22077246'), "\n\n  <h2><a href=\"http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22077246-promise-me-this?from_choice=false&amp;from_home_module=false\" class=\"readable\">Promise Me This (Between Breaths, #4)<\/a><\/h2>\n\n  <div>\n    by <a href=\"/author/show/7060187.Christina_Lee\" class=\"authorName\">Christina  Lee<\/a><span title=\"Goodreads Author!\">*<\/span>\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"smallText uitext darkGreyText\">\n    <span class=\"minirating\"><span class=\"stars staticStars\"><a class=\"staticStar p10\" size=\"12x12\" title=\"4.13 of 5 stars\">4.13 of 5 stars<\/a><a class=\"staticStar p10\" size=\"12x12\" title=\"4.13 of 5 stars\"><\/a><a class=\"staticStar p10\" size=\"12x12\" title=\"4.13 of 5 stars\"><\/a><a class=\"staticStar p10\" size=\"12x12\" title=\"4.13 of 5 stars\"><\/a><a class=\"staticStar p3\" size=\"12x12\" title=\"4.13 of 5 stars\"><\/a><\/span> 4.13 avg rating &mdash; 388 ratings<\/span>\n    &mdash; published 2014\n  <\/div>\n\n    <div class=\"addBookTipDescription\">\n      \n<span id=\"freeTextContainer3494377565927542800\" class=\"elementOne\">\n  A new love will test the boundaries of passion between a privileged boy next door and the tattooed, blue-haired girl who helps him embrace his wild side...\n\n\nNate has developed quite a playboy reputation around campus. It\'s not that he doesn\'t respect or trust women; he doesn\'t trust himself. The men<\/span>\n  <span id=\"freeText3494377565927542800\" class=\"elementTwo\" style=\"display:none\">\n  A new love will test the boundaries of passion between a privileged boy next door and the tattooed, blue-haired girl who helps him embrace his wild side...\n\n\nNate has developed quite a playboy reputation around campus. It\'s not that he doesn\'t respect or trust women; he doesn\'t trust himself. The men in Nate’s family are prone to abusive behavior—a dirty secret that Nate’s been running from his entire life—so Nate doesn\'t do relationships. But he can’t help himself around one girl…\n\nJessie is strong, independent, and works at a tattoo parlor. Nate can’t resist getting close to her, even if it’s strictly a friendship. But it doesn\'t take long for Nate to admit that what he wants with Jessie is more than just friendly.\n\nWith Jessie, he can be himself and explore what he’s always felt was a terrifying darkness inside him. Even when Nate begins to crave her in a way that both shocks and horrifies him, Jessie still wants to know every part of him. Testing their boundaries together will take a trust that could render them inseparable… or tear them apart.<\/span>\n  <a data-text-id=\"3494377565927542800\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"swapContent($(this));; return false;\">...more<\/a>\n    <\/div>\n\n\n\n", { style: 'addbook', stem: 'leftMiddle', hook: { tip: 'leftMiddle', target: 'rightMiddle' }, hideOn: false, width: 400, hideAfter: 0.05, delay: 0.35 });
  $('bookCover646987_22077246').observe('prototip:shown', function() {
    if (this.up('#box')) {
      $$('div.prototip')[0].setStyle({zIndex: $('box').getStyle('z-index')});
    } else {
      $$('div.prototip')[0].setStyle({zIndex: 6000});
    }
  });

  newTip['wrapper'].addClassName('prototipAllowOverflow');

    $('bookCover646987_22077246').observe('prototip:shown', function () {
      $$('div.prototip').each(function (e) {
        if ($('bookCover646987_22077246').hasClassName('ignored')) {
          e.setStyle({'display': 'none'});
          return;
        }
        e.setStyle({'overflow': 'visible'});
      });
    });
  $('bookCover646987_22077246').observe('prototip:hidden', function () {
    $$('span.elementTwo').each(function (e) {
      if (e.getStyle('display') !== 'none') {
        var lessLink = e.next();
        swapContent(lessLink);
      }
    });
  });

//]]>
</script>


            </div>
```

I am new with php and Xampp and have already surfed internet for help but was of no use.
I have connected Apache from Xampp control pannel, have made a save.php page wherein I wrote the following:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.goodreads.com/genres/new_releases/art');
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@name="coverWrapper"]')->item( 0);

echo $node->textContent;
?>
```

This gives me an error on 11th Line
Error:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ind\save.php on line 11

Comment: I would highly recommend their [api](https://www.goodreads.com/api). Usually websites that provide an API want you to use it, as opposed to wasting their bandwidth and yours by scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something as simple as this, I'd save myself the headache and skip xpath... You're already reading the HTML into a text string, it'll probably be easier to process $html as a string. For example:

You know the title of the book on the page you're looking at is between `class=\"readable\"` (which only shows up the one time in the document) and `<\/a>`.

For the image, there is only a single img tag, so the following src attribute should always belong to the img tag, so code similar to the following will slice it out pretty quickly.

```
$imgStart = stristr ($html, '<img'); // get the start of the img tag
$srcStart = stristr(subtr($html, $imgStart), 'src="');
$srcStart += 5; // Offset for the chars src="
$srcEnd = stristr((subtr($html, $srcStart), '"');
$imgSrc = substr($html, $srcStart, $srcEnd - $srcStart);
```

Super robust? No... But you're screen-scraping, and there's no real robust way to do that, since you're always depending so much on the precise structure or syntax of someone else's code.

Also be sure that the terms of use of the site you're using allow scraping. Lots of sites really frown on that.